# Python 3.11.3 - Web3 6.4.0 - Python reports that contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens does not have attribute buildTransaction

Tags: attributes, token, pancakeswap

I have now Python 3.11.3 and Web3 6.4.0 and I cannot use anymore my old code for buying/selling tokens in Pancakeswap because Python reports that contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens does not have attribute buildTransaction

How Can I modify my code for using it in Web3 6.4.0 ?

thanks

#this is for BUYING

```
tokenToBuy = web3.to_checksum_address(tokenAddress)
spend = BNBTokenAddress  #wbnb contract address
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeSwapRouterAddress, abi=pancakeABI)
nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress)

start = time.time()


pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
0, 
[spend,tokenToBuy],
walletAddress,
(int(time.time()) + transactionRevertTime)
).buildTransaction({
'from': walletAddress,
'value': web3.to_wei(float(snipeBNBAmount), 'ether'), #This is the Token(BNB) amount you want to Swap from
'gas': gasAmount,
'gasPrice': web3.to_wei(gasPrice,'gwei'),
'nonce': nonce,
})

try:
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key)
    tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction) #BUY THE TOKEN
except Exception as e:
    print(e)


txHash = str(web3.to_hex(tx_token))


#TOKEN IS BOUGHT

checkTransactionSuccessURL = "https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=transaction&action=gettxreceiptstatus&txhash=" + txHash + "&apikey=" + bscScanAPIKey
checkTransactionRequest = requests.get(url = checkTransactionSuccessURL)
txResult = checkTransactionRequest.json()['status']


if(txResult == "1"):
    print(" Successfully bought $" + tokenSymbol + " for " + style.BLUE + str(snipeBNBAmount) + " BNB - TX ID: ", txHash)
    time.sleep(10) #wait for tx to confirm
    
else:
    print("Transaction failed: likely not enough gas.")


#THIS is for SELLING

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=pancakeSwapRouterAddress, abi=pancakeABI)
spend = BNBTokenAddress #wbnb contract address
#Approve Token before Selling
start = time.time()
approve = sellTokenContract.functions.approve(pancakeSwapRouterAddress,   tokenValue).buildTransaction({
        'from': walletAddress,
        'gasPrice': web3.to_wei(gasPrice,'gwei'),
        'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress),
        })

try:
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(approve, private_key=private_key)
    tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    print("Approved: " + web3.to_hex(tx_token))
except Exception as e:

    print("Already been approved")
    pass
return


#Wait after approve 5 seconds before sending transaction
time.sleep(5)
tokenSymbol = sellTokenContract.functions.symbol().call()
print(f"Swapping {tokenReadableBal} {tokenSymbol} for BNB")

time.sleep(5) # wait for approval to confirm

#Swapping exact Token for ETH 
pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactTokensForETH(            tokenValue ,0,                 [tokenContractAddress, spend],            walletAddress,            (int(time.time()) + transactionRevertTime)).buildTransaction({            'from': walletAddress,            'gasPrice': web3.to_wei(gasPrice,'gwei'),            'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(walletAddress),            })

try:
signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key=private_key)
tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(f"Sold {tokenSymbol}: " + web3.to_hex(tx_token))
except Exception as e:

    print( "Price impact too high, can't be sold at this moment. Will retry shortly.")
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change the function `buildTransaction()` by `build_transaction()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.